# How can I detect an exe installed from an HTTP server using SNORT

Tags: snort, ids, alert

alert tcp any any -> any 80 (msg:"HTTP File Download Detected"; flow:to_server,established; content:"GET "; http_method; content:".exe"; http_uri; sid:1000001;)

On wireshark it looks like this : GET /reverse.exe HTTP/1.1
however cant seem to get an alert working on snort